# How to change frame for each UIButton in view

Tags: uitableview, ios, ios4, uibutton

I'm trying to update every frame for an allocated UIButton when the device's orientation is updated. Right now I have a for loop that's supposed to check for every UIButton in the view and update the frame of the UIButton. The for loop is not working though, can anyone tell me why?

Thanks in advance!

```
for(UIView* view in theTable.subviews) {
    if([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        NSLog(@"UIButton found");
        view.frame = CGRectMake(430, 10, 23, 24);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `[view setNeedsDisplay];` after changing the frame. From the documentation:

> You can use this method or the
>   setNeedsDisplayInRect: to notify the
>   system that your view’s contents need
>   to be redrawn. This method makes a
>   note of the request and returns
>   immediately. The view is not actually
>   redrawn until the next drawing cycle,
>   at which point all invalidated views
>   are updated.